# SOAP client is not able to authenticate with mutual tls

Tags: java, soap, client-certificates, mtls

I have an Apache CXF client that is connecting a SOAP service, and authenticating with mutual TLS. The client fails during the TLS Handshake because the service sends an empty list of client certificates to the server. I am testing this with self-signed certs, and I can prove that my server works with a curl request and with postman. I am pretty sure that the certificates are setup correctly, and I am sure that I am missing a config step in the CXF client.

Here is how I have my client setup

```
// setting up certs & keystores
String keystore = "client-keystore.jks";
String keystorePassword = "changeit"; // local self-signed certs

String trustStore = "truststore.jks";
String trustStorePassword = "changeit"; // local self-signed certs

// client keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystore), keystorePassword.toCharArray());

// ca truststore
KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ts.load(new FileInputStream(trustStore), trustStorePassword.toCharArray());

// key managers
var kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ks, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

// trust managers
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ts);
TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

TLSClientParameters param = new TLSClientParameters();
param.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLSv1.2");
param.setDisableCNCheck(false);
param.setTrustManagers(tms);
param.setKeyManagers(kms);

// Get the client & setup the tls parameters
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
var client = ClientProxy.getClient(bp);

HTTPConduit https = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
https.setTlsClientParameters(param);
```

Here is how I created the certificates. My java version is azul zulu openjdk 11.

```
# Create the CA Authority that both the client and server can trust
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj '/CN=my-ca' -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt
 
# Create the server's key, certificate signing request, and certificate
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -subj '/CN=localhost' -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 365 -out server.crt
 
# Create the client's key, certificate signing request, and certificate
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -key client.key -subj '/CN=my-client' -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 365 -out client.crt
openssl x509 --in client.crt -text --noout
 
# Create the root truststore
keytool -import -alias my-ca -file ca.crt -keystore truststore.jks
 
# Create pkcs12 file for key and cert chain
openssl pkcs12 -export -name server-tls -in server.crt -inkey server.key -out server.p12
 
# Create JKS for server
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore server-keystore.jks -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias server-tls

# Create pkcs12 file for key and cert chain
openssl pkcs12 -export -name client-tls -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12

# Create JKS for client
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore client-keystore.jks -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias client-tls
```

I set debugging on with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake,data` for both the server & the client.

When I use the CXF client to issue a request to the server, it initiates the mutual tls handshake, but the server fails with `Fatal (BAD_CERTIFICATE): Empty server certificate chain`, and the client fails with `Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking...readHandshakeRecord`, because it does indeed send an empty certificate list right before hand.

```
Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
```

I have tried a number of different things, but I cannot seem to get the client to work.

**Update**
Out of curiosity, I ran the [ws-security sample](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/ws_security/ut_policy) from the CXF repo, and used my ca certificate, client, and server certificates in the sample. That worked, and it is configured through an xml bean. I tried the same thing with my local, and it still fails.

The difference between the demo and my client is that when it looks for a x.509 RSA certificate, it fails for my client, but succeeds in the demo app. I have it configured mostly the same.

```
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.039 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.040 EDT|CertificateMessage.java:1066|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.040 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.040 EDT|CertificateMessage.java:1066|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.040 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.040 EDT|CertificateMessage.java:1066|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.040 EDT|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|01|main|2021-07-02 14:17:32.040 EDT|CertificateMessage.java:1066|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256
```

That last error is not present when using the demo app and instead, it returns back the certificate.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, here's how I resolved it.

Once I started playing with the CXF demo code, I was able to simplify it to just its bare minimum set of dependencies and configurations. From there I was able to sort out that it was a matter of a missing dependency in my project.

For starters, we use dropwizard for the server, and we have a dependency on dropwizard-jaxws which brings in the cxf dependencies. I found by whittling away all of the layers, that the demo app only works if `cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty` is in the list of dependencies.

The transitive dependencies that dropwizard-jaxws include are:

```
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws
cxf-rt-transports-http
```

I also had a dependency on all of dropwizard-core in my client which may have implemented some SPI interface that `cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty` implements (conjecture). Once I simplified the dependencies and included the one missing dependency, I have a repeatable, working solution.